# How to launch application threw "a href" on the foreground instead of background

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer

In my project i am using "a href" to launch windows application.

```
 <a href={`some app here`}>
//Similar logic to mailto
```

The problem is, that it launch it on the background instead of bringing it up on the foreground.
Basically it just sits and blinks in Windows task bar instead of automatically appear on top of the screen.

Does anyone knows is there any specific way how with a tag bring it on the foreground  automatically instead of background?

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely have to use javascript for this. If that is fine, use this code here:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 

     APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 

     BORDER="no"

     CAPTION="no"

     SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"

     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"

     SYSMENU="yes"

     SCROLL="no"

     WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
  WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:RunFile()">Run the Notepad application</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You would replace the notepad.exe in c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe with the application file that you want to run. Hope this helps!